# Highcharts 'marker' line padding

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

The chart is generated as image.

my problem this is:

[image]

Last marker, cutting circle. Generatting

Thank you!!

Comment: Without code here is a guess - you are ending on tick point and/or setting xAxis max to the last point's xAxis. So it is cut off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings to look at to stop this from happening:

1) maxPadding (and minPadding) - http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.maxPadding

2) endOnTick (and startOnTick) - http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.endOnTick

The chart will not adjust to account for the size of your markers automatically - if you use large markers, and have tightly controlled axes, you will need to make some adjustments accordingly.